# How would I select the first image in this div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pseudo-element

I have this div with a bunch of other divs and images.  The main div is m-carousel-inner.  What I want to do is select the first img element within this div.  How would I go about doing this in javascript or jquery?

```
<div class="m-carousel-inner">

<div class="m-item">
<div class="m-card-light">
<div class="mqc_img">
<img src="http://placehold.it/280x210">
</div><!-- end .mqc_img -->
<div class="mqc_info">
<h5>Title</h5>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div><!-- end .mqc_info -->
</div>
</div>

<div class="m-item">
<div class="m-card-light">
<div class="mqc_img">
<img src="http://placehold.it/280x210">
</div><!-- end .mqc_img -->
<div class="mqc_info">
<h5>Title</h5>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div><!-- end .mqc_info -->
</div>
</div>

<div class="m-item">
<a href="#">
<div class="m-card-light">
<div class="mqc_img">
<img src="http://placehold.it/280x210">
</div><!-- end .mqc_img -->
<div class="mqc_info">
<h5>Title</h5>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div><!-- end .mqc_info -->
</div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="m-item">
<div class="m-card-light">
<div class="mqc_img">
<img src="http://placehold.it/280x210">
</div><!-- end .mqc_img -->
<div class="mqc_info">
<h5>Title</h5>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div><!-- end .mqc_info -->
</div>
</div>

<div class="m-item">
<div class="m-card-light">
<div class="mqc_img">
<img src="http://placehold.it/280x210">
</div><!-- end .mqc_img -->
<div class="mqc_info">
<h5>Title</h5>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div><!-- end .mqc_info -->
</div>
</div>

<div class="m-item">
<div class="m-card-light">
<div class="mqc_img">
<img src="http://placehold.it/280x210">
</div><!-- end .mqc_img -->
<div class="mqc_info">
<h5>Title</h5>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div><!-- end .mqc_info -->
</div>
</div>

<div class="m-item">
<div class="m-card-light">
<div class="mqc_img">
<img src="http://placehold.it/280x210">
</div><!-- end .mqc_img -->
<div class="mqc_info">
<h5>Title</h5>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div><!-- end .mqc_info -->
</div>
</div>

<div class="m-item">
<div class="m-card-light">
<div class="mqc_img">
<img src="http://placehold.it/280x210">
</div><!-- end .mqc_img -->
<div class="mqc_info">
<h5>Title</h5>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div><!-- end .mqc_info -->
</div>
</div>

<div class="m-item">
<div class="m-card-light">
<div class="mqc_img">
<img src="http://placehold.it/280x210">
</div><!-- end .mqc_img -->
<div class="mqc_info">
<h5>Title</h5>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div><!-- end .mqc_info -->
</div>
</div>

<div class="m-item">
<div class="m-card-light">
<div class="mqc_img">
<img src="http://placehold.it/280x210">
</div><!-- end .mqc_img -->
<div class="mqc_info">
<h5>Title</h5>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div><!-- end .mqc_info -->
</div>
</div>

<div class="m-item">
<div class="m-card-light">
<div class="mqc_img">
<img src="http://placehold.it/280x210">
</div><!-- end .mqc_img -->
<div class="mqc_info">
<h5>Title</h5>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div><!-- end .mqc_info -->
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- end .m-carousel-inner -->
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Like this?

```
$('.m-carousel-inner').find('img:first');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMagg/)**

See **[:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)**

First part `$('.m-carousel-inner')` is the selector for your container element with class `.m-carousel-inner` which will return the jquery wrapped DOM element, and apply `.find('img:first')` to find the first instance of img as its child at any level.

Answer (score 2):

in jquery you could

```
<script>$('.m-carousel-inner img:first');</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use jQuery `first()` function with the jQuery selector

```
<script> $('.m-carousel-inner img').first(); </script>
```