# Select Object ID from multiple Object IDs

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, shopify

I have the current HTML code:

```
<div class="container" onMouseOver"testfunction(this)">
  <img id=test1 />
  <div id=test2>
    <iframe id=test3></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the current Javascript function:

```
// This way every container in the page change always the first id=image of the page

    function testfunction(obj)
      {
          $('#test1').css("display","none"); 
      }
```

How can I get the current object image id, is it possible using this type of setup?

already tried a few options but none of them works properly:

```
$('#' + 'obj.test1').css("display","none");
$(obj.test1).css("display","none");
```

Comment: How can I get the current object image id - here you mean to say that image id from the current hovering object? And will it have always 1 image tag or it can be multiple image tag?

Comment: @TarunDudhatra Yes, when overing a current object I want it to make changes to the current object image ID but instead of doing that, what happens is that no matter what object you have the mouse over it only changes the first object of the page because I think my code is currently aiming to the first image id of the page and I don't want that

Comment: @TarunDudhatra Do you have any idea to fix this? It's probably an easy fix but I don't really know how to code javascript so can't really figure it out how to fix it :(

Comment: try with below code, it will search for img tag into current hovering div

 `function testfunction(obj)
      {
          $(obj).find("img").css("display","none"); 
      }`

Comment: @TarunDudhatra Yeap, thanks a lot! It's working

Comment: If you want to use jQuery, here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602283/how-would-i-select-the-first-image-in-this-div-with-jquery

Comment: @Fábio Oliveira, glad to hear that it worked,  you can upvote that answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you actually want but I hope this answers.

**Note:** It's important that the img element is the first one inside the div with the "container" class.

If you want the id value of the img:

```
function testfunction(x){
  var id = x.children["0"].id;
  console.log(id);
}
```

If you want the img to disappear:

```
function testfunction(x){
  x.children["0"].style.display="none";
}
```